# Finding inflection point

Tags: calculus

I have a function given where I need to find the inflection point:
$$y = (x^2 + 3\frac 34)\sqrt{x}$$
The first derivative is:
$$y'= 2x\sqrt{x} + (x^2 + 3\frac 34)\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$
The second derivative is:
\begin{align}
y'' & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} + \frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x}} + \left(x^2 + 3\frac 34\right)\left(-\frac{1}{4x}\right)\\
& = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} + \frac{x}{\sqrt{x}} - \frac{x^2 + 3\frac 34}{4x} \\ 
& = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} + \sqrt{x} - \frac{x^2 + 3\frac 34}{4x}\\
\end{align}
To find the inflection point I need to equal the second derivative to $0$:
$$0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} + \sqrt{x} - \frac{x^2 + 3\frac 34}{4x}$$
Now I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Multiplying out the original function and *then* differentiating twice would yield a simpler form of the equation to solve...

Comment: Really, you'd rather get rid of those brackets right away.

Comment: The second derivative don't look right...

Answer (score 1):

Your first derivative is correct but your second derivative is incorrect. I'll simplify your first derivative to make the second derivative less error-prone.

$$\begin{align}
y' &= 2x\sqrt{x} + (x^2 + 3\frac 34)\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} \\[2 ex]
 &= 2x^{3/2}+\frac 12(x^2+\frac{15}4)x^{-1/2} \\[2 ex]
 &= 2x^{3/2}+\frac 12x^{3/2}+\frac{15}8x^{-1/2} \\[2 ex]
 &= \frac 52x^{3/2}+\frac{15}8x^{-1/2} \\[4 ex]
y''&= \frac{15}4x^{1/2}-\frac{15}{16}x^{-3/2} \\[2 ex]
 &= \frac{15}4\sqrt x-\frac{15}{16x\sqrt x}
\end{align}$$

(I checked the first and second derivatives on my graphing calculator and they check out.)

Set that expression for $y''$ equal to zero and multiply both sides by $x\sqrt x$ and you get a solvable equation.